# Word 2013 crashes when converting to Adobe PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, crash, adobe-acrobat

When a user on our terminal server right-clicks a Word Document and selects *convert to Adobe PDF*, it crashes. (image below)
The user is able to convert PDFs via manually opening the Word document and saving it as PDF, but this isn't as convenient.

Word 2013 version 15.0.4953.1001 and Adobe Acrobat Standard 9.5.5.
It seems to work fine for myself as an admin user.

- Task manager never shows a spike in resource usage when this happens
- The crash always happens when you're prompted to save the PDF document somewhere after Word opens (image below)
- The crash happens for all Word documents

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compatibility problems between Acrobat and Office 2013 [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdfmaker-unavailable-office-2007-office.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to save a document as PDF in Word 2013.

In File > Save as click in Save as type box and choose PDF.

Or else in File > Print click in Printer box to open the drop-down menu and select Microsoft Print to PDF, then click on the Print button.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these, and these work for the user (as specified in my question) but they aren't as convenient or fast as simply right clicking the file and selecting Convert to Adobe PDF.